# Dynamically generating values that proceed in groups of 5

Tags: javascript

I am working on pagination which works with the following logic:

```
  if (currentPage > 5 && currentPage < 11) pages = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
  if (currentPage > 10 && currentPage < 16) pages = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
  if (currentPage > 15 && currentPage < 21) pages = [16, 17, 18, 19, 20];
  if (currentPage > 20 && currentPage < 26) pages = [21, 22, 23, 24, 25];
```

However, rather than hardcoding these values, I'd like to write a dynamic version of this, as much as is possible. If you notice, there are always five clickable page numbers on each page, represented by the values in the pages array. But I'm unclear on how to accomplish this.

Comment: Round down the current page number to the nearest 5 `Math.floor(pageNum / 5) * 5`, then add next 5 numbers to the array.

Comment: Wouldn’t it make more sense to show the 5, or so, _nearest_ pages? E.g. for `currentPage === 7`, `pages` being `[ 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]`. Other than that, this is less of a JS question and more of a math question. Use math operators to calculate some `offset`, then use something like [`Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_, index) => index + offset)`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Divide the `currentPage` by 5.
2. Round that `value` *up*, and subtract 1. This is important because in your snippet, you are keeping the multiples of 5 at the *end*.
3. Create an array of 5 items starting that that `(value * 5) + 1`, and increment for the length of the array.

```js
function createPageRange(currentPage) {
  const startingPageMultiple = Math.ceil(currentPage / 5) - 1;
  const startingPage = (startingPageMultiple * 5) + 1;
  return Array(5).fill().map((_, i) => i + startingPage);
}

console.log('currentPage = 1', createPageRange(1));
console.log('currentPage = 5', createPageRange(5));
console.log('currentPage = 6', createPageRange(6));
console.log('currentPage = 18', createPageRange(18));
console.log('currentPage = 21', createPageRange(21));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
currentPage = 5;
pages = [];

pages = setPages(currentPage);

function setPages(num) {
begin = (currentPage%5)*5+6;
pages.length=0;
for (let i=0; i<5; i++) {
  pages.push(begin++);
}
return pages;
}

console.log(pages);
currentPage = 11;
pages = setPages(currentPage);
console.log(pages)
```